# Perl, check if last char is a bracket

Tags: arrays, perl, match

I want to check the last char of an array entry, if it's a bracket or not.

My code looks like this:

```
        my $lastchar = substr $blub[8],-1,1;
        print "$lastchar..............................\n";
        if ($lastchar == "\(" )
        {
            splice @blub, 8, 2, join('', @blub[8,9]);
        }
```

But this code don't works... it matches every bracket, when it's an open "(" or a closed bracket ")"...

Thanks in advance.
Regards, John.

Comment: You should use eq, not ==

Comment: wow, that was fast. works fine. if you make this as an answer i would accept it. but why eq?

Comment: `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. Help Perl to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others mentioned, you need to use `eq` rather than `==` for string comparison.

[`eq` tests string equality, while `==` tests numeric equality](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators).  This is necessary because Perl is dynamically typed.  It needs to know whether you want to treat something as a number or a string.  For example, `"123.00"` is numerically equivalent to `"123"`, but the two are not string equivalent.

In your original code, Perl took the numeric portion of each `$lastchar` and `"\("` and compared them.  However, since neither has any numbers, the "numeric portion" of each was equivalent to zero, and the comparison was always true.

You should always `use warnings; use strict;` in your code.  If you had warnings enabled, you would have gotten a warning about non-numeric values in a comparison.

However, it would be more Perlish and simpler to use a regex for this:

```
if ($blub[8] =~ /\($/)
{
    splice @blub, 8, 2, join('', @blub[8,9]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `eq` (`==` is for numbers and `eq` is for strings) and just `"("` (there is no need to escape it here)

```
    my $lastchar = substr $blub[8],-1,1;
    print "$lastchar..............................\n";
    if ( $lastchar eq "(" )
    {
        splice @blub, 8, 2, join('', @blub[8,9]);
    }
```